# [GraphQL error]: Message: Unknown argument "email" on field "createUser" of type "rootMutation"., Location: [object Object], Path: undefined

Tags: reactjs, graphql

I am using express graphql and apollo client here. I am facing a problem on a mutation

.......................................................................................................................

My error :

> [GraphQL error]: Message: Unknown argument "email" on field
>   "createUser" of type "rootMutation"., Location: [object Object], Path:
>   undefined

When i am clicking register button , it is giving me an error. 
my component :

```
import { useMutation } from "@apollo/react-hooks";
import { gql } from "apollo-boost";

const CREATE_USER = gql`
  mutation createUser($email: String!, $password: String) {
    createUser(email: $email, password: $password) {
      _id
      email
    }
  }
`;

function Register() {
  const [email, setEmail] = React.useState("");
  const [password, setPassword] = React.useState("");
  const [createUser, { data }] = useMutation(CREATE_USER);

  return (
    <div class="row">
      <div class="input-field col s12">
        <input
          id="email"
          type="text"
          class="validate"
          onChange={e => setEmail(e.target.value)}
        />
        <label for="email"> Email </label>
      </div>
      <div class="input-field col s12">
        <input
          id="password"
          type="password"
          class="validate"
          onChange={e => setPassword(e.target.value)}
        />
        <label for="password"> Password</label>
      </div>
      <button
        className="btn"
        onClick={() => {
          createUser({
            variables: { $email: email, $password: password }
          });

          console.log(data);
        }}
      >
        Register
      </button>
    </div>
  );
}

export default Register;
```

My schema :

````
``` type User {
  email: String!,
  password: String,
  createdEvents:[Event!]
  }

  type rootMutation {
           createUser(userInput: UserInput): User,

}```
````

Comment: Can you show your UserInput type in your schema?

Comment: why negative ?...

Answer (score 1):

Your mutation receives an UserInput argument, not email and password directly.

```
const CREATE_USER = gql`
  mutation createUser($userInput: UserInput) {
    createUser(userInput: $userInput) {
      _id
      email
    }
  }
`;

...

  <button
    className="btn"
    onClick={() => {
      createUser({
        variables: { userInput: { email, password } }
      });

      console.log(data);
    }}
  >
    Register
  </button>
```